# why does webpack gives error when run npm run dev

Tags: node.js, laravel, webpack, command-line-interface

I'm trying to run "npm run dev" in my laravel project but there is an error occured that saying:
Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/package.json'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\abdal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\20792\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
  at Function.resolve (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:78:19)
  at runCli (C:\Users\abdal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\20792\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:50:26)
  at C:\Users\abdal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\20792\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:139:5
  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
  'C:\Users\abdal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\20792\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js'
  ]
  }

Note that the webpack cli has been downloaded.

Comment: did you run "npm install"  and what folder are you using in the command line interface ?

Comment: It seems you are missing the `webpack-cli module`. So first run `npm install --save-dev webpack-cli` to install [webpack-cli](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli) and then run `npm run dev` again.

Comment: @IslamElHakmi
I removed node_modules folder from my project and run npm install again and everything is fine now but it said that : run mix again!
what does that mean?

Comment: @codedge
I did that before but returns the same result!
As I said in the previous comment:I removed node_modules folder from my project and run npm install again and everything is fine now but it said that : run mix again! what does that mean?

Comment: @AbdallahMYassin try `npm run watch` if it didn't work try the solution in this issue: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1475

Answer (score 3):

Try running the following.

```
npm install -g webpack-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this below steps:

1. Clear the log file resides on the `directory(*****\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs)`
2. `npm i -g webpack-cli`  [Execute this command]
3. `npm install && npm run dev`